# Making linkage between two objects in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

For example, I have 2 list, consits of these data

```
List1               List2               

Group1              Group1's value1             
blank               Group1's value2             
blank               Group1's value3             
blank               Group1's value4             
Group2              Group2's value1             
Group3              Group3's value1
```

When transfered to report, they became.

```
oList1 = Group1 + chr(10) + blank + chr(10) + blank + chr(10) + blank + chr(10) + Group2 + chr(10) + Group3 
oList1 = Group1's value1  + chr(10) + Group1's value2  + chr(10) + Group1's value3  + chr(10) + Group1's value4  + chr(10) + Group2's value1  + chr(10) + Group3's value1
```

The report's layout (header section) :

[image]

Expected result :

[image]

But if one of the value's length exceeds the text object's width, the result will be like below :

[image]

Is there any workaround to solve this? I'm thinking calculating the display size of the text to determine how many lines it would take to display on the report. But that feels risky!

Comment: Why is it necessary to put in variable `oList`? Why can't you just get it as separate column instead?

Comment: @crs Thanks for the reply, assuming they are separate columns, the issue still there right ?

Comment: Please see my answer whether it is applicable for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I would just put the `Group` and `Value` as separate column in the report. Put it in the `Details` section, like below:

[image]

Then, I will set the `Value` to be able to grow, if it exceeds the report width:

[image]

That would eliminate the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think you are misunderstanding my problem. The object is placed at the header section, not  the detail section. That's why I am using the oList variable and the line feed carriage for line breaks.

Comment: It should work even if you put in the header section. You can move the object to the header portion if that's the case.

Comment: and the issue is still there!

Comment: Can you post what it looks like when using it in the header?

Comment: it looks exactly like the picture I posted above, sorry, the machine I'm using can't connect to the internet

Comment: When you say it looks like the picture you posted, are you using the oList variable or not ?

Comment: I'm using the olist variable

Comment: That's why it does not make any difference. You need to use the column from your dataset